# boost::python and callback driven execution

Tags: python, multithreading, boost-python, gil

I'm having problems on [a project](https://github.com/tgirod/pyck) that involves a boost::python and callback-driven execution.

My project is using a callback mechanism to run some python code from C++.

As long as the initial function call causing my callback execution is coming from the python interpreter, everything is fine. For example:

```
h = CallbackHandler()

def mycallback():
    print "yeah"

h.setCallback(mycallback)

h.runCallback()

# will print yeah
```

Alas, it is not that simple. My project uses [RtAudio](http://www.music.mcgill.ca/~gary/rtaudio/) to communicate with the audio environment. RtAudio's execution is callback-driven: I give to RtAudio a callback function, and when I start RtAudio, the callback is called everytime sound needs to be computed.

When using RtAudio's callback-driven execution, I get a segfault as soon as my code tries to run a python callback from C++.

To start the callback-driven execution, I have to make a call to the function start(), which is non-blocking. It means that the callback-driven execution happens in another thread.

Then, when calling start() from python, I'm creating another thread separately accessing python's execution environment. From my little understanding of python's GIL, this is not good.

So, How can I make this callback-driven thread run python callbacks without breaking everything up ?

Sorry, I couldn't find a way to simplify my code to a short, fully functional example of my problem ... [the problem is located there](https://github.com/tgirod/pyck/blob/master/pyck/core.cpp#L237).

**EDIT**

After looking around in the [python documentation](http://docs.python.org/c-api/init.html#non-python-created-threads), I added a few lines of code that are supposed to handle thread safety when a non-python created thread is trying to access to the python environment :

```
gstate = PyGILState_Ensure();
while (!queue.empty() && queue.top()->next <= now ) {
    queue.top()->run();
    queue.pop();
}
PyGILState_Release(gstate);
```

But I still get a segfault. So I ran it through valgrind, and here is what I get (minus the weird stuff valgrind always gets from the python interpreter, which is "normal") :

```
==31836== Thread 2:
==31836== Invalid read of size 4
==31836==    at 0x41F0DD5: sem_post@@GLIBC_2.1 (in /lib/libpthread-2.14.1.so)
==31836==    by 0x5ED294C: callback(void*, void*, unsigned int, double, unsigned int, void*) (in /home/tom/Code/pyck/pyck/libcore.so)
==31836==    by 0x5F6B16B: RtApiAlsa::callbackEvent() (in /usr/lib/librtaudio.so)
==31836==    by 0x5F6BBCC: alsaCallbackHandler (in /usr/lib/librtaudio.so)
==31836==    by 0x42D286D: clone (in /lib/libc-2.14.1.so)
==31836==  Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==31836== 
==31836== 
==31836== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==31836==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x0
==31836==    at 0x41F0DD5: sem_post@@GLIBC_2.1 (in /lib/libpthread-2.14.1.so)
==31836==    by 0x5ED294C: callback(void*, void*, unsigned int, double, unsigned int, void*) (in /home/tom/Code/pyck/pyck/libcore.so)
==31836==    by 0x5F6B16B: RtApiAlsa::callbackEvent() (in /usr/lib/librtaudio.so)
==31836==    by 0x5F6BBCC: alsaCallbackHandler (in /usr/lib/librtaudio.so)
==31836==    by 0x42D286D: clone (in /lib/libc-2.14.1.so)
==31836==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==31836==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==31836==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==31836==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==31836==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.
==31836== 
==31836== HEAP SUMMARY:
==31836==     in use at exit: 2,313,541 bytes in 2,430 blocks
==31836==   total heap usage: 22,140 allocs, 19,710 frees, 22,007,627 bytes allocated
==31836== 
==31836== LEAK SUMMARY:
==31836==    definitely lost: 522 bytes in 5 blocks
==31836==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==31836==      possibly lost: 66,669 bytes in 1,347 blocks
==31836==    still reachable: 2,246,350 bytes in 1,078 blocks
==31836==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==31836== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==31836== 
==31836== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==31836== Use --track-origins=yes to see where uninitialised values come from
==31836== ERROR SUMMARY: 2703 errors from 196 contexts (suppressed: 83 from 13)
```

If I get it right, my callback function is trying to access a NULL pointer right ?

**EDIT 2**

Ok, I'm discovering all this. From [pthread's documentation](http://osr600doc.sco.com/man/html.PTHREAD/sem_post.PTHREAD.html), it looks like there is a call to `sem_post(sem)`, where `sem` points to a semaphore. But there it points to NULL.

Now, how can I pinpoint the error more precisely ?

Comment: Try running your program under valgrind to better diagnose the source of the problem.

Comment: @John : added valgrind result

Comment: My guess is that your semaphore problem is an implementation bug in the queue you're using.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are running afoul of the GIL. My guess is that the callback code is not acquiring the GIL before diving into the Python interpreter.

It might also be that all the threads that are going to use the GIL have to register themselves before they can do so. And the thread executing your callback has not registered itself.

I would set it up so the C++ callback didn't execute a Python callback. Instead it writes the relevant data into a socket that your Python program is reading from. Then your Python program can execute the callback when it gets the relevant data from the socket.